# How do I get input onchange results without submit?

Tags: reactjs

I tried to get onChange value using useState and I should loop input tag
but the tag looks same and nobody knows how many input is gonna be added so What i want to do is push the array without submit button.

this is test code and Im going to do mapping to it
I tried to do like this :

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Test = () => {
  const [labelName, setLabelName] = useState("");
  const [labelContainer, setLabelContainer] = useState([]);

  const getTextValue = e => {
    setLabelName(e.target.value);
    setLabelContainer([...labelContainer, labelName]);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      num1 YAXIS:
      <input type="text" onChange={getTextValue} />
      num2 YAXIS:
      <input type="text" onChange={getTextValue} />
      num3 YAXIS:
      <input type="text" onChange={getTextValue} />
      <h1>num1 YAXIS:{labelContainer[0]}</h1>
      <h1>num2 YAXIS:{labelContainer[1]}</h1>
      <h1>num3 YAXIS:{labelContainer[2]}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

but i can't get the results each .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you need?

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
export default function Test(props){
  const [labelName, setLabelName] = useState("");
  const [labelContainer, setLabelContainer] = useState([]);

  const getTextValue = (e,index) => {
    setLabelName(e.target.value);
    let temp=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(labelContainer));
    temp[index]=e.target.value;
    setLabelContainer(temp);        
  };
  return (
    <div>
      num1 YAXIS:
      <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>getTextValue(e,0)} />
      num2 YAXIS:
      <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>getTextValue(e,1)} />
      num3 YAXIS:
      <input type="text" onChange={(e)=>getTextValue(e,2)} />
      <h1>num1 YAXIS:{labelContainer[0]}</h1>
      <h1>num2 YAXIS:{labelContainer[1]}</h1>
      <h1>num3 YAXIS:{labelContainer[2]}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```